# Problem with \ProcessOptions?

Tags: class-options

I recently bought a new laptop and installed latest complete MiKTeX and Texmaker, which is the editor I use on my other laptop. Compiling the same document on my new laptop doesn't give the same output than with my other one.

More specifically, in most of my documents, I call a .cls file with all the stuff that I don't want to copy-paste every time. On my new laptop, it seems that the options I declare are not processed. Here is a minimal (not) working example: first a .cls file, then another file calling my class.

```
\ProvidesClass{TEST}
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\pouet}{0}
\DeclareOption{OPT}{\renewcommand{\pouet}{1}}

\ProcessOptions
```

```
\documentclass[10pt,OPT]
{C:/path/TEST}

\begin{document}

\pouet

\end{document}
```

Here, I don't get any error, but it prints 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Don't call your class with an explicit path. Instead, put it in a path where MikTeX finds it (e.g., the local directory) and load it without the path, that way the options should work.

Comment: Loading a class or package with an explicit path is not really something encouraged.  As Skillmon said you should move it to a path where MiKTeX can find, or to the same folder as your document.  That said, this was already reported [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/422) and it's already fixed in the development repository.  A patch release should be out in a couple of weeks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was fixed in the kernel